# How to make my code works in all sheets, and not only in a current active sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Now I manage to have this code works well in my activesheet:

```
Sub Deletecells()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
     For Each ws In Worksheets
       Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = Last To 1 Step -1
          If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "DELETE" Then
           Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
          End If
        Next i
   Next ws
End Sub
```

But I can only run it in one sheet (the sheet I put the macro in), so how do I modify the code so it can run in all sheet in the workbook? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a With ... End With block to provide parent worksheet reference for all Cells and Rows calls (converted to .Cells and .Rows to pass the reference).

```
Sub Deletecells()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, last as long
   For Each ws In Worksheets
     with ws
       Last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = Last To 1 Step -1
          If ucase(.Cells(i, "A").Value) = "DELETE" Then
            .Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
          End If
        Next i
     end with
   Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again @Jeeped! That works awesomely well! I didn't know what's wrong with my code, and found that you put 'last as long' there in the code. Could you enlighten me what it's for? It's my first time seeing the function in use.

Comment: @user71812 It declares your variable `Last` as type `Long`. All variables that are used in VBA should be declared a type like `Dim Variable As Type` before you use them. A good idea is to use `Option Explicit` that remembers you to declare all variables so you don't forget it. See [Option Explicit Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, wonderful. Thanks so much for the explanation, will go check the link you provided now. Have a good day!